# How to update entry? SQlite/Android/ToDo App

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Learning how to program in android by following a tutorial but i am trying to also update the entry in the data base though not entirely how to do so. Any help please?

```
package dev.edmt.todolist;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by reale on 06/10/2016.
 */

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME="EDMTDev";
    private static final int DB_VER = 1;
    public static final String DB_TABLE="Task";
    public static final String DB_COLUMN = "TaskName";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT NOT NULL);",DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN);
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = String.format("DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS %s",DB_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertNewTask(String task){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }

    public void editTask(String task){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);

        db.update(DB_TABLE,values,DB_COLUMN + " = " + task,null) > 0;
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteTask(String task){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DB_TABLE,DB_COLUMN + " = ?",new String[]{task});
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTaskList(){
            ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]{DB_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
            taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

More specifically this part, cant really say i quite understand the way it works:

```
public void editTask(String task){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);

db.update(DB_TABLE,values,DB_COLUMN + " = " + task,null) > 0;
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.update` method will create SQL statement according to your given parameters and execute it. You could see the `db.update()` method to find a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> More specifically this part, cant really say i quite understand the
>   way it works:

**It may work, as in not fail, but as explained below it probably does nothing of any use.**

The SQLiteDatabase `update` method is a convenient way of issuing the SQL to perform an update. It writes/creates the underlying SQl, executes it, and also returns the result (the number of rows updated).

Using your code as an example, to do the similar without using the `update` method you could create the SQL :-

```
UPDATE Task SET TaskName = 'your_value' WHERE Task = 'your_value'
```

- Note that this is actually useless as you are effectively saying *(assuming for demonstration that the value passed to the editTask method is **task001**)*; **Update** the task row(s) that has/have the value of **task001** in the **TaskName** column to be changed from **task001** to  **task001**.
- Note the `update` method uses `UPDATE OR IGNORE......` so :-

> - When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the IGNORE resolution algorithm skips the one row that contains the constraint
>     violation and continues processing subsequent rows of the SQL
>     statement as if nothing went wrong. Other rows before and after the
>     row that contained the constraint violation are inserted or updated
>     normally. No error is returned when the IGNORE conflict resolution
>     algorithm is used. [SQL As Understood By SQLite - ON CONFLICT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

#### Suggestion

Perhaps what would be more useful if say you wanted to change a row that before the update, has a value **task001**. Changing it say to **task002**.

in this case the SQL could be :-

```
UPDATE Task SET TaskName = 'your_new_value' WHERE Task = 'your_original_value'
```

Your `editTask` method could then be :-

```
public void editTask(String original_task, String new_task){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_COLUMN,new_task);
    db.update(DB_TABLE,values,DB_COLUMN + " = '" + original_task + "'" ,null) > 0;
    db.close();
}
```

- e.g. using  `edittask("task001","task002");`
- Note how the value original_task is enclosed in single quotes.

**However**, the recommended way, would be to utilise arguments (which would automatically be enclosed in quotes) so the above could be :-

```
public void editTask(String original_task, String new_task){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_COLUMN,new_task);
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{original_task};
    db.update(DB_TABLE,values,DB_COLUMN + "=?",whereargs) > 0;
    db.close();
}
```

- each **?** coded in the WHERECLAUSE (3rd parameter) replaced by the respective argument in the WHEREARGS (4th parameter) on a 1 by 1 basis.

---

#### Additional

In addition to creating the SQL, the `update` method also invokes the SQL using an appropriate means e.g. it does the equivalent of `db.execSQL(your_sql)` for you.

---

Additionally in the case of `update` it then does the equivalent of :-

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT total_changes()",null);
int total_changes = 0;
if(csr.moveToFirst()) {
    total_changes = csr.getInt(0);
}
return total_changes;
```

Hence returning the number of updated rows.